# pymqi correlId length

Tags: python, ibm-mq, mq, pymqi

I work with pymqi, version 1.12.0

I tried to put msg with correlId into a queue, when I get back the msg, I recived just part of the correlId (first 24 chars).
I saw that the length of the correlId defined under CMQC: MQ_CORREL_ID_LENGTH=24

How can I change the default length so it would fit different correlIds length?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671181/jms-correlation-id-getting-truncated , I think.

Comment: As Mark said below, CorrelId has a fixed size of 24 bytes.  You need to use a CorrelId that is not larger than 24 bytes or simply set the string you want to use as a Message Property (aka Named Property).  See here for an example: https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/blob/master/code/examples/message_property_set.py

Answer (score 1):

The MQMD CorrelId is fixed at 24 bytes (not characters). That can't be changed. Different language bindings may do different things with inputs that are not exactly that length (padding/truncation) and may or may not give error returns, but 24 is the underlying length.